# Successful login IP address list

Tags: 22.04, ssh

I know I need to look in /var/log/auth.log but I don't seem to have been able to grep only successful IP addresses.
I wish to output to another file in a format:

```
Accepted from <username /> from <ipaddress /> port <port /> at <datetime />
```

The purpose of this will be a cron job run by a development nginx webserver which will run a cron job to record and only allow page access to the most recent IPs that have logged in also by ssh, using a publickey (if this gives some context).

Comment: Something like `grep -Eo 'Accepted password for [a-z]+ from [0-9\.]+ port [0-9]+' /var/log/auth.log` ?

Comment: Replace `password` in the command with `publickey`

Comment: … or use a RegEx "or" `|` modifier like `[password|publickey]` or make it match all authentication methods like  `[a-z]+` or even `[.]+` @user68186 … Let’s see if that is actually what OP expected, I'm not quite sure of that yet.

Comment: You’re welcome @user68186 Without the `[]` then `|` will split the whole string and not just those to expressions’ so matching either `Accepted password` or `publickey …` (it should)  however the `+` is a quantifier meaning one or more and is not needed for this … The last one is my mistake `.` inside `[]` will be literal matching an actual dot … So use `.+` instead of `[.]+` and it should work matching any one or more characters.

Comment: Great comments, many thanks. I have updated question as also I need a timestamp and to output just this info to another file that nginx can read

Comment: Some great answers here, but they are comments :) please post an answer as these are very close to what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was very tired when I wrote this, and I know that there are probably better ways to do this.  But here is my attempt.

I am guessing that you want the timestamp of each line found to be printed at the end of each line.  I wrote this up really quickly using `awk` and I think there probably is a much better way to do this, but by using `awk` we can grab the positional columns.  `awk` assumes that [[spaces]] are field separators.

If we do an `awk` line like the following:

```
awk '/Accepted publickey/ {print}' /var/log/auth.log
```

The `/Accepted publickey/` is the exact match we are looking for, and `{print}` without any fields will print the entire line to the screen, so then we get a line like the following:

```
Jan 15 21:11:07 terrance-ubuntu sshd[468972]: Accepted publickey for terrance from 127.0.0.1 port 52736 ssh2: RSA SHA256:<MyReallyLongKey>
```

`awk` assumes spaces as field separators by default.  If you want something else like a colon `:` you would specify it at `-F:` before the `'/Accepted publickey/'`.  With the spaces as the field separators go, field `1` would be Jan, `2` would be 15, `3` would be 21:11:07, so on and so forth.

With `awk` you specify which field you want to print by `{print $1,$2}` and so on.

Grabbing just what you put in your question the fields would be 1, 2, 3, then 6 - 13.  Also, `awk` can print out the fields in any order you want separated by commas, and you can also write in text in "quotes":

```
awk '/Accepted publickey/ {print $6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,"at",$3,"on",$1,$2}' /var/log/auth.log
```

I know the `awk` line is ugly, but it will produce a line like:

```
Accepted publickey for terrance from 127.0.0.1 port 52736 at 21:11:07 on Jan 15
```

Then to write this out to a log that is owned by root use the `tee -a` command.

`tee` means `read from standard input and write to standard output and files` and the `-a` means to append to the file.

So, your command can look like the following:

```
awk '/Accepted publickey/ {print $6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,"at",$3,"on",$1,$2}' /var/log/auth.log | sudo tee -a /var/www/security/ssh_ips.log
```

Comment: thanks, especially for the explaination of the commands

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
grep -Po 'sshd.*\KAccepted publickey for [a-z]+ from [0-9.]+ port [0-9]+' /var/log/auth.log >> /path/to/outfile
```

Where [`grep`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html)'s options `-P` will enable Perl style regular expressions [PCREs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man3/pcresyntax.3.html) (to use `\K`) and `-o` will print the capturing parts of the match only.

`sshd` will ensure the line has that to only match SSH related authentication lines in the log ... `\K` will exclude what is on its left from printing so you don't get it in the output.

`Accepted` will match successful authentication as per the authentication log syntax.

`publickey` will only match that authentication method, but you can include other methods like `password` by splitting them by an "or" `|` modifier like e.g. `[publickey|password]` to match both or to match any alphabetical expression (word/method), you can use `[a-z]+` or even match any one or more charachters with `.+`.

`[a-z]+` should match alphabetical lower-case (usernames), `[0-9.]+` should match numeric and dots (IPs) and `[0-9]+` should match numeric (ports) ... Notice `+` is a quantifier that will match at least one or more of the previous expression/s.

So, the whole RegEx should match a line like this:

```
2024-01-16T17:26:34.896742+03:00 localhost sshd[1140156]: Accepted password for ubuntu from 127.0.0.1 port 54208 ssh2
```

... to print it like so:

```
Accepted password for ubuntu from 127.0.0.1 port 54208
```

... and the shell append redirects `>>` will append output to the file named `outfile` at the path `/path/to/outfile` and will create it if it doesn't exist.

Notice that if used in CRON as a cronjob, then it's advised to specify the full path to the executable like `/bin/grep` instead of just `grep` as the latter will rely on your search path to resolve and that might be different from the search path variable available to CRON especially when invoked as the user `root` or if added to the system-wide crontab.

For further processing and formatting, you can also use other more resourceful text processing tools like e.g. AWK:

```
awk '
/sshd.*Accepted .+ for [a-z]+ from [0-9.]+ port [0-9]+/ {
        print "Accepted from <" $7 " /> from <" $9 " /> port <" $11 " /> at <" $1 " />"
}
' /var/log/auth.log >> /path/to/outfile
```

... to print something formatted to your liking:

```
Accepted from <ubuntu /> from <127.0.0.1 /> port <54208 /> at <2024-01-16T17:26:34.896742+03:00 />
```

Comment: getting sudo grep -Po 'sshd.*\KAccepted publickey for [a-z]+ from [0-9.]+ port [0-9]+' /var/log/auth.log >> /var/www/security/ssh_ips.log -bash: /var/www/security/ssh_ips.log: Permission denied

Comment: @Datadimension Try that same command as `grep -Po 'sshd.*\KAccepted publickey for [a-z]+ from [0-9.]+ port [0-9]+' /var/log/auth.log | sudo tee -a /var/www/security/ssh_ips.log`

Comment: thats nearly perfect, except is there a way to get a timestamp in the output

Comment: @Datadimension You need to consider the timstamp format used in your `auth.log` and adjust the AWK script to do that for you ... For example the AWK script in my answer will print the time stamp and work correctly as is only if the timestamp format is like `2024-01-16T17:26:34.896742+03:00`  ... While @Terrance's answer highloghts possible dealing with timestamp formatted like `Jan 15 21:11:07` ... You can include an exact example of an actual `... Accepted publickey for ...` line from your log in your question and reflect it in your desired output format to get more specific solutions.

Comment: … @Datadimension Just a reminder to filter out personal credentials identifiers when copying and pasting  examples to your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -i ssh /var/log/auth.log | grep -i accept | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f11 | sort -u
```

this will list all ssh login ip from auth.log sorted.

Comment: Thanks, this did not quite work for me, it just gave a list of numbers, but still useful